# WPF Extended Toolkit - Color Spectrum Slider Extension

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

Is it possible to extend the ColorSpectrumSlider in Xceed WPF toolkit to have two sliders to select the range of colors, I mean, i want to get a range of GradientStops which are within two sliders?